# Django register api with two User profile models

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am trying to create user, where User model has two User profiles, e.g. Teacher and Student. At the time of creating user, I want to create User instance in Teacher or Student profile also.

Here's my Serializer classes:

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id', 'user_id')


class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('id', 'user_id')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
            'user_type'
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

Here's the custom register view:

```
class CreateUserView(CreateAPIView):

    model = User
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny # Or anon users can't register
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Right now, I am able to create User and but creating user profile according to the `user_type` parameter is a challenge for me.

So, if `user_type` is **student**, I need to create User instance for the StudentProfile as well(a new row in student profile table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can add simple if condition?:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
    if validated_data('user_type') == 'student':
        Student.objects.create(user_id=user.id)
    else:
        Teacher.objects.create(user_id=user.id)
    return user
```

Comment: I forgot to add, I have  `create_student_profile` method in Student model and I was trying to call this method to create student instance.

Comment: And above code works very well, but I am still unsure why I can't use `create_student_profile`